# How can I fix the Go error that appears after restarting the terminal that no downloaded packages were found?

Tags: go

Wrote a simple program for the test:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)
func main() {
    e := echo.New() 
    fmt.Printf("YEEEEEEES!")
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

And when `go run main.go` it prints `YEEEEEEES!` and starts the server :1323.

But after restarting (close and reopen) the terminal (Bach) and re-entering (in the same path) the same command `go run main.go` already produces an error:

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/labstack/echo/v4" in any of: 
        C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\labstack\echo\v4 (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\lol20\go\src\github.com\labstack\echo\v4 (from $GOPATH)
```

Assumed that the problem could be in `Echo`, but with `Iris` the situation was the same.

Checked, the computer has a path `C:\Users\lol20\go\src\github.com\labstack\echo`, but no `C:\Users\lol20\go\src\github.com\labstack\echo\v4` (difference in \v4 at the end). I suppose this is the problem, because from the error it is clear that the search is performed in the path `C:\Users\lol20\go\src\github.com\labstack\echo\v4`.

Please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because non english title

Comment: Sounds like the shell's environment changed between the restarts of the terminal. Anyway you should be using modules instead of GOPATH. Run [`go mod init [module-path]`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Initialize_new_module_in_current_directory) and then [`go mod tidy`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_missing_and_remove_unused_modules). Reading [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code) may also help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try switching `GO111MODULE="on"` as follows: `go env -w GO111MODULE=on` (switching with `export GO111MODULE="on"` only works until the shell environment changes (before restarting the terminal))